# A function that takes one line of JavaScript and returns a possible line comment trimmed

Tags: javascript, string, null, comments, trim

If the line contains no line comment, null should be returned.

`cutComment('let foo; // bar')` should return 'bar', but its returning 'let foo; // bar'.

```js
function cutComment(comment) {
  if (comment === null) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return comment.replace(/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|\/\/.*/g, '').trim();
  }
}

console.log(cutComment('let foo; // bar'));
```

Comment: It's actually returning `let foo;` as you can see from the snippet of your code I added.

Answer (score 1):

changed the regex to match anything that comes after `//`

```js
function cutComment(comment) {
 if(!comment) return null

 let match = comment.match(/(?<=\/\/).+/)
 if(match.length > 0 ) {
    return match[0]
  }else{
   return null
 }
}

console.log(cutComment('let foo; // bar'));
```

Comment: cutComment('let foo; // bar') does not return 'bar', but ' bar'. I have tried return match[0].trim as well as return match[0].tostring.replace(“ ”,””) still I am not able to remove space before bar

Comment: use ```match[0].trimStart()```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with the help of previous examples of jshero

```
let cutComment = (a) => {
    let i = a.indexOf('//');
    console.log('value of i'+i);
    let str = a.substr(i+3);
    console.log(str);
    if (i === -1) {
         return null;
    }
    return str;
}
```